# Files are overwriting instated of appending in BeanShell PostProcessor Jmeter while running 1000 threads

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have written below code under beanshall post-processor. But when I am running 1000 threads the files are overwriting existing content instated of appending. It is working for 1-5 threads. Can anyone help me on this?

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
File fExceptionLog = new File("${logPath}/ExceptionLog.txt");
String extExceptionData= FileUtils.readFileToString(fExceptionLog);
id=vars.get("id");
try{
String cDatestamp="${__time(yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS)}";
String cResponce = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
String cRequest = prev.getQueryString();
String cResponceCode=prev.getResponseCode();
cTransactionName = prev.getSampleLabel();
cResponseTime = prev.getTime();
cSize = prev.getBytesAsLong();
cIsSuccessful =prev.isSuccessful();
File fRequestLog = new File("${logPath}/RequestLog.txt");
File fHitLog = new File("${logPath}/HitLog.txt");
File fResponceLog = new File("${logPath}/ResponceLog.txt");
File fErrorLog = new File("${logPath}/ErrorLog.txt");
String extHitData = FileUtils.readFileToString(fHitLog);
String extRequestData = FileUtils.readFileToString(fRequestLog);
String extResponceData = FileUtils.readFileToString(fResponceLog);
String extErrorData = FileUtils.readFileToString(fErrorLog);
log.info("cResponceCode"+cResponceCode);
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(fHitLog,extHitData+id+"~"+cDatestamp+"~"+cTransactionName+"~"+cResponceCode+"~"+cResponseTime+"~"+cSize+"~"+cIsSuccessful+"\n"); 
if(cResponceCode.equals("200")){
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(fRequestLog,extRequestData+id+"~"+cDatestamp+"~"+cTransactionName+"~"+cResponce+"\n");
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(fResponceLog,extResponceData+id+"~"+cDatestamp+"~"+cResponceCode+"~"+cResponce+"\n");
}else{
  FileUtils.writeStringToFile(fErrorLog,extErrorData+id+"~"+cDatestamp+"~"+cTransactionName+"~"+cResponce+"\n"+id+"~"+cDatestamp+"~"+cResponceCode+"~"+cResponce+"\n");
}
}catch(Exception e){
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(fExceptionLog,extExceptionData+id+"~"+cDatestamp+"~"+cTransactionName+"~"+e+"\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're violating at least 3 [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

1. You're referring [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like `${logPath}` while you should be using `vars` shorthand instead like `vars.get("logPath")`
2. You're using Beanshell while [starting from JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 and Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
3. And last but not the least, you yourself introduced a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) so when several threads will be concurrently writing the same file it will result in data loss. You can put this Beanshell test element (along with the parent Sampler(s)) under the [Critical Section Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller), but it will reduce concurrency of the parent sampler(s) to only one at a time

If you need to write some some metrics into a custom file in your own format I would rather recommend consider migrating to the [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/) which is extremely "flexible" with regards to what values is to store and it accumulates multiple entries in memory and flushes them periodically in batch manner so all the data will be stored without collisions.

You can install Flexible File Writer using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @dmitri T I have  Flexible File Writer for writing the customized files but looks like i am unable to use |variable#<N>| and current timestamp in milliseconds. I also tried the Critical Section Controller it is working but my load decreased to 5 from 1000. Can you help me achiving above requirement ?

Comment: |variable#<N>|~|${timedate}|~|responseTime|\t|latency|\t|sentBytes|\t|receivedBytes|\t||responseCode|\r\n

Comment: User Defined Variables 
timedate - ${__time(yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS)}

Comment: anyone can help me on this ?